# C# how to set dropDownList default value for selectedValue = null

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a `dropdownlist1` that has has 6 collection items including `Select One`. What I want is this ddl is set to `Selectedvalue` = null. But what I am getting is my ddl always selecting `Select One` as its initial value. My ddl properties for `Select One` is selected:false. How to set this ddl to initial selected value = null?

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Visible="False" Width="146px">
     <asp:ListItem>Ceiling Speaker</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>Remote Microphone</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>Digital Source Player</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>Remote paging Console</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>Modular Mixer</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>Select One</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>


if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSearchProductname.Text))
{
   if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == null)
   {
       txtProductName.Text = "";
   }
   else
   {
       SqlProductmaster.InsertParameters["ProductName"].DefaultValue = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();
   }
}
else
{
    SqlProductmaster.InsertParameters["ProductName"].DefaultValue = txtProductName.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an 'Empty' value item:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="146px">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Ceiling Speaker</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Remote Microphone</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Digital Source Player</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Remote paging Console</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Modular Mixer</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Select One</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Then you would check for

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(DropDownList1.SelectedValue))
```

Comment: I did as you said but when I insert something in txtProductName, it not displayed in browser.

Comment: However weird it is, my problem regarding to this question is being solved by only replacing txtProductName.Text = ""; with SqlProductmaster.InsertParameters["ProductName"].DefaultValue = txtProductName.Text;
Working like charm though.

Answer (score 3):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server"> 
    <asp:ListItem Text="(Select a State)" Value="" />   
    <asp:ListItem>Ceiling Speaker</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Remote Microphone</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Digital Source Player</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Remote paging Console</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Modular Mixer</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Select One</asp:ListItem>    
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: @Alex Still not displayed.You see, my ddl somehow affecting textbox txtProductName. it Should display what I type in txtProductName first. Should i leave it be, and I  select ddl item, then selectedValue will fill in. Or, I can leave both empty, still getting result as i want.

Answer (score 2):

SelectedValue of a dropdownlist would never be null. It could be empty string, but it can never be null...

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to set the Items in this fashion

```
<asp:ListItem Text="Select One" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
```

Also `SelectedValue` of the Dropdown is a string property so better check the same using `string.IsNullOrEmpty` as it cannot be null, leave the value blank where you want to consider it as null and repeat the same values in the `Text` and `Value` part for others

Answer (score 0):

Hera add a default value in the lsit...

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="146px">
<asp:ListItem Selected="True">Select One</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Ceiling Speaker</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Remote Microphone</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Digital Source Player</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Remote paging Console</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Modular Mixer</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Select One</asp:ListItem>
```

but try something like seleted item instead of  selectedvalue  beacuse u have'nt defined values in the list items..

```
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(DropDownList1.SeletedItem))
```

For textbox also

```
  txtProductName = DropDownList1.SeletedItem).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CancelSelectOnNullParameter = False on the SqlDataSource

Answer (score 0):

Make the select value="" that is empty and pass this to your stored procedure like this

```
 dt = ta.GetData(
            String.IsNullOrEmpty(DropDownList1.SelectedValue)? null : DropDownList1.SelectedValue,
            String.IsNullOrEmpty(DropDownList2.SelectedValue) ? null : DropDownList2.SelectedValue,
            String.IsNullOrEmpty(DropDownList3.SelectedValue) ? null : DropDownList3.SelectedValue, null);
```